# unsatisfied constraints appear after adding a AVPlayerViewController Programatically

Tags: ios, objective-c, nslayoutconstraint, ios-autolayout, avplayerviewcontroller

I have been adding `AVPlayerViewcontroller` Programatically like this

```
     playerViewController = [[AVPlayerViewController alloc]init];
     playerViewController.view.frame = CGRectMake(40,60, 500, 700);
     playerViewController.showsPlaybackControls=YES;
     [self.view addSubview:playerViewController.view];
```

I am getting so many constraints warning

```
> <NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraint:0x14defa560 h=-&- v=-&- _UIBackdropContentView:0x14deae530.width == _UIBackdropView:0x14deab370.width>",
"<NSLayoutConstraint:0x14dee1b70 H:|-(14)-[UILabel:0x14dee0ea0'Hi-Speed Scrubbing']   (Names: '|':_UIBackdropContentView:0x14deae530 )>",
"<NSLayoutConstraint:0x14dee1bf0 H:[UILabel:0x14dee0ea0'Hi-Speed Scrubbing']-(14)-|   (Names: '|':_UIBackdropContentView:0x14deae530 )>",
"<NSLayoutConstraint:0x14dee1670 H:|-(0)-[_UIBackdropView:0x14deab370]   (Names: '|':UIView:0x14deab090 )>",
"<NSLayoutConstraint:0x14dee16f0 H:[_UIBackdropView:0x14deab370]-(0)-|   (Names: '|':UIView:0x14deab090 )>",
"<NSLayoutConstraint:0x14dee1330 H:|-(0)-[UIView:0x14deab090]   (Names: '|':AVAlphaUpdatingView:0x14deaaad0 )>",
"<NSLayoutConstraint:0x14dee13b0 H:[UIView:0x14deab090]-(0)-|   (Names: '|':AVAlphaUpdatingView:0x14deaaad0 )>",
"<NSLayoutConstraint:0x14defb080 'UIView-Encapsulated-Layout-Width' H:[AVAlphaUpdatingView:0x14deaaad0(0)]>"
```

I have also tried giving

```
playerViewController.view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO
```

Still I am getting Constraints issues. Could anyone please give me a solution?

Comment: Are you sure you get constraints warning only after adding playerViewController to your view hierarchy.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should not set frame of your `playerviewcontroller`. You can manage it something like,

```
 NSURL *videoURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"url string here"];
AVPlayer *player = [AVPlayer playerWithURL:videoURL];
AVPlayerViewController *playerViewController = [AVPlayerViewController new];
playerViewController.player = player;
[self presentViewController:playerViewController animated:YES completion:nil];
```

or you can add `playerViewController's view` to `self.view` instead of presenting it like,

```
 [self.view addSubview:playerViewController.view];
```

**Update :**

Try this,

```
 NSURL *videoURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"url string"];
AVPlayer *player = [AVPlayer playerWithURL:videoURL];
AVPlayerLayer *playerLayer = [AVPlayerLayer playerLayerWithPlayer:player];
playerLayer.frame = self.view.bounds;
[self.view.layer addSublayer:playerLayer];
[player play];
```

And make sure that if you have another controls like `label` or `button` then you have set proper constraints to that.

Comment: i need to playerviewconrtoller as a view ..while adding as subview I am getting constraints issue

Answer (score 0):

Use autolayout on your playerViewController.